# How to translate a SQL query to a HQL one?

Tags: java, sql, hql

How can the following SQL query be translated into a HQL query?

```
select c.*, count(o.*)

from Cooperativa as c
     left join Operatore as o on c.id = o.id_cooperativa

where c.flag_cancellazione = 0

group by c.id 

order by c.id desc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look and do R&D
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm
http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/Dev/HqlTutorial

For more reference :
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html